# Rendering a DOM-Node as a String without specifying namespaces in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

a project of mine using Java needs to output XML based on an abstract representation, which is modelled as an own class/datatype. Considering this function

```
public static String renderToString(Node element) {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = null;
    try {
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(element);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
    try {
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.getWriter().toString();
}
```

I have written a test that constructs an Element equivalent to

```
<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="8000" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
```

This is generated by the following function

```
public static Element createFieldElement(Document doc) {
    Element fieldElement = doc.createElement("FIELD");
    ...
    fieldElement.setAttribute("xsi:type", "CharTerm");
    return fieldElement;
}
```

Passing this Element to the function I now get an error telling me that the 'xsi' namespace is missing (which was used with the xsi:type attribute), which makes sense since the Element I try to render is no complete XML document.

**Is there an option I must set or any way to bypass the XML Namespace declaration in order to keep my code testable?**

Otherwise I would try to mock some functions to trick the Transformer into rendering the Element anyway, but I would not suggest that a convenient option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found no way to omit the namespace checking, but for the sake of testing I found a compromise by adding the namespace while testing.

```
@Test
public void IfColumnDescriptionGivenThenGenerateAccordingField() {
    Element element = XSDCreator.createFieldElement(doc, 1, ";");
    element.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    String output = XSDCreator.renderToString(element);
    assertEquals(output, "Here comes the output");
}
```

This may not be the real output, but this should be sufficient for testing purposes. Another approach would be to generate a Document with a proper namespace declaration and render the whole document.